# RVM bundle not found

Tags: ruby, rvm

I just installed rvm and then the bundler gem.

```
➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.7.0]
➜  ~  gem list|grep bundler
bundler (1.0.12)
```

But when I try to run the bundle command then I got the following error:

```
➜  ~  which bundle
bundle not found
```

The interesting thing is that it works if I prepend "rvm ruby"

```
➜  ~  rvm ruby bundle
```

Still, I don't think like I should prepend rvm ruby before any command. Is this behavior correct?

**EDIT:** apparently the problem is that the default configuration is not remembered between shells.

If I type "rvm 1.8.7 --default" then it works, but as soon as I open a new shell it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was that I had .rvm/bin on my path on .zshrc, which was causing all kind of troubles

Answer (score 7):

Run `$ rvm use 1.8.7` and you should be good. The reason for this is that rvm will use the system ruby/gems unless you specify otherwise. You can verify this by running `which ruby` and checking the path.

You can set the default ruby with rvm as well, like so: `$ rvm --default use 1.8.7`.

Comment: that works, but it forgots after I open a new shell. To clarify, the ruby interpreter is still correct, it just can't find gem executables anymore.

Comment: Are you setting the default this way, or the way in your question? And did you follow the instructions related to `return` and .bash_rc?

Comment: I set it as you mentioned. The nice thing is that which ruby returns the correct ruby, it's just the gem executables that are not found. Perhaps I need to create a .rvmrc file on my home directory?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me :

```
rvm gemset list

rvm gemset use global
```

More details here : http://marcgrabanski.com/gem-management-with-rvm-and-bundler/